# SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm writing a simple JDBC code with MySQL. Everything works fine and I'm able to print the records in table through select statement. But when I'm closing the connection, using Connection.close(), I'm getting the below exception. Any help is appreciated.

```
 WARN: Caught while disconnecting...
EXCEPTION STACK TRACE:
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
javax.net.ssl.SSLException
MESSAGE: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
 STACKTRACE:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:255)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:645)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:624)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.quit(NativeProtocol.java:1312)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.quit(NativeSession.java:182)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:1750)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:720)
    at com.jdbc.Driver.display(Driver.java:27)
    at com.jdbc.Driver.main(Driver.java:38)
```

Comment: Go through this once -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html. There might be some problem with the setup.

Comment: I was trying to connect to Oracle DB from Databricks using pyspark and I was getting the same error, for me the root cause was using TCPS connection protocol without specifying `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` in option() while calling dataframe.write().

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was a issue with the MySQL driver on Java 11 https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93590

This has been fixed in Connector/J version 8.0.16

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround is to disable [SSL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html) by appending `?useSSL=false` to the JDBC URL.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:port/database_name?useSSL=false
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I was getting this issue when executing an AWS Glue Crawler with a JDBC MySQL Connection and appending the useSSL=false resolved it.